# Plotting Several Functions w.r.t. Sqrt[variable]

Tags: plotting

I have the following plots in Mathematica but I would like to plot them with respect to Sqrt[s] instead of s. How would I do that?

```
p1 = Plot[{Abs[
 Subscript[f, 1][s]/(s - (Subscript[σ, 1][s])^2)]/191.36, 
 Abs[Subscript[f, 5][s]/(s - (Subscript[σ, 5][s])^2)]/38, 
 Abs[Subscript[f, 50][s]/(s - (Subscript[σ, 50][s])^2)]/4, 
 Abs[Subscript[f, 100][s]/(s - (Subscript[σ, 100][s])^2)]/
2.48878}, {s, 3.5, 5.0}, PlotLegends -> {"0.1", "0.5", "5", "10"},
PlotLabel -> 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\) amplitudes: M=2.1, \
 \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(1\)]\)=\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \
 \(2\)]\)=1", PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"E", "|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \(1\)]\)|"}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: It is good practice to present a minimal example, rather than just cutting and pasting the code you  are working on.  You are more likely to get a helpful response if you do.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) (although sometimes it messes up the ticks):

```
Plot[Sin[Pi s], {s, 1, 8}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Sqrt, #^2 &}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The ticks seem to be log-scale choices.  Here's a way around that if desired:

```
Plot[Sin[Pi s], {s, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Sqrt, #^2 &}, Automatic}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear", {Sqrt, #^2 &}, "Nice"], Automatic}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Block` to effect a change of plot variable e.g.

```
Block[{s = sqrts^2},
 Plot[Sinc[Pi s], {sqrts, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]]
```